# Select option from dynamic dropdown list using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill out the dropdown menus found on this [homepage](http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html) using Python and the selenium package. To Select Make I am using the following code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get('http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html')

button = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
ActionChains(driver).click(button).perform()

select_make = driver.find_element_by_id('vehicle-make')
Select(select_make).select_by_value("BMW")
```

However this does not seem to actually "Select the BMW" option. I tried to follow the method explained in [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver) post. Can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think I've resolved the issue by setting the select to visible, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question you linked to the accepted answer iterates over the options and finds the matching text.

```
select_make = driver.find_element_by_id('vehical-make')
for option in select_make.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'BMW':
        option.click() # select() in earlier versions of webdriver
        break
```

Running this in Java I got the message that the element is not visible, so I forced it:

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.tirerack.com/content/tirerack/desktop/en/homepage.html");
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    driver.findElement(By.tagName("button")).click();

    WebElement select_make = driver.findElement(By.id("vehicle-make"));
    select_make.click();

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    String jsDisplay = "document.getElementById(\"vehicle-make\").style.display=\"block\"";
    js.executeScript(jsDisplay, select_make);

    for (WebElement option : select_make.findElements(By.tagName("option"))) {
        System.out.println(option.getText());
        if ("BMW".equals(option.getText())) {
            option.click();
            break;
        }
    }
```

If you add the JavascriptExecutor lines (in python) I think it will work.

Comment: I had tried this and while this avoids the error, this does not actually assign the vehicle make. In order to have access to the vehicle year tab, a vehicle make must be selected.